# MongoDB C#/VB.Net Driver Send multiple nested queries

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have 2-3 collections and from MongoDB shell i can have a single
query as below:

```
db.Products.distinct("ProdName",{_id:{"$in":db.Order.distinct("ProdID",{"OrderID" : 555})}})
```

this works fine, i have not used Embedded approach as my collection size is in millions so it is not fesible.

My question is related to C#, can we pass the above mongoQuery in single call or instruct mongodb not to fetch until told? Currently it seems there are 2 database calls happening from C#, but from MongoDB its just single call below is c# code to fetch result

```
Dim mongoQuery1 = Query.EQ("OrderID", iOrderID)

Dim collection1 = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Order").Distinct("ProdID", mongoQuery1)

Dim ProdIDs = collection1.ToArray()

Dim newBsonArray1 = New BsonArray(ProdIDs)
Dim mongoQuery2 = Query.In("_id", newBsonArray1)

Dim collection2 = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("Products").Distinct("ProdName", mongoQuery2)
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> db.Products.distinct("ProdName",{_id:{"$in":db.Order.distinct("ProdID",{"OrderID" : 555})}})

In this `mongo` shell example you are actually executing two queries on the MongoDB server, despite the appearance of a single query with a function call. The `mongo` shell will resolve any variables (including your call to `db.Order.distinct()`) before sending the query to the server.

If you're not convinced, you can check this using the MongoDB database profiler:

```
// Enable profiling for all queries
db.setProfilingLevel(2)

// Run the "single" query
db.Products.distinct("ProdName",{_id:{"$in":db.Order.distinct("ProdID",{"OrderID" : 555})}})

// Disable profiling
db.setProfilingLevel(0)

// Query for the profile entries distinct command
db.system.profile.find({ "op":"command", "command.distinct": { $exists: true }})
```

The equivalent C# code will also involve two queries, since you are querying two different collections. MongoDB (as at 2.6) explicitly does not support single queries that involve multiple collections (aka ["joins"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#what-kind-of-database-is-mongodb)).

Comment: Hi Stennie, I agree to you but my issue is here in c# i unneccessaryly require to query and store the data at client side and resend it as input to next query as a result it increases memory and network utilization, so is it possible to send the query as shell query in C# to MongoDB at one shot, and it is fine if MongoDB internally executes it seperately

Comment: @Ajay: I think you may be confused on what the `mongo` shell is doing; whether you appear to send this as "one statement" or two, it is still always going to execute as two queries so the resource usage is identical. In the `mongo` shell the first query and fetch is *still* happening with round trip to the `mongo` shell (aka the "client" in this example) before the second query is executed. The shell query is not "one shot", it is two queries executed sequentially. Invoking the `mongo` shell via C# is going to add complexity, not save it.

Comment: Hi Stennie, I agree that at MongoDB end there will be 2 execution, but is there anyway to send just the shell script to mongoDB and let the execution happen at MongoDB end (whether it seperates in multiple call). The issue here is say in my example provide the Order will retrieve millions of prodids from mongodb and will have to save temporarily in client side , drawback here is 1st huge network bandwidth usage and 2nd temporary memory for saving at client side. So if i am able to send a script or text command then in this case i will benefit, so just want to know is it possible to send query

Comment: @Ajay: No, the "single query" you're asking for is not possible. If you try the same query from the `mongo` shell it's also going to pull all the results back to the shell client before running your `distinct()` query. If you are retrieving *millions* of prodids from `Order` to join with `Product`, that sounds like a painfully large query. I would suggest you look into an [Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) approach for a much more efficient result.

Comment: Since you are merging data from multiple collections, I would suggest looking into [Incremental Map-Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/). This pattern will allow you to progressively update your results in a collection (for example, based on order date) so you're not re-running the whole aggregation from the start each time. There's a blog post from a few years ago with a relevant example: [Using MongoDB MapReduce to join 2 collections](http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/).

Comment: Thanks Stennie for the details, i will check the link provided by you for MapReduce.